# Getting a file not found exception, be cause the path doesn't get formatted properly

Tags: java, mysql, filenotfoundexception

I am using windows, and in the java code im creating a query which looks like,

" LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'F:/cust_files/1360235457810_customer_xlsx.xlsx.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE customer.temp_20130207_10098_1360235533471505000 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ;"

but when i run the application i get and file not found exception and the path looks like, 
F:cust_files1360235457810_customer_xlsx.xlsx.csv

java.io.FileNotFoundException
MESSAGE: F:cust_files1360235457810_customer_xlsx.xlsx.csv (The system cannot find the file specified) 
Can someone let me know what causes this and what can be the solution

Comment: Can you post the code where you care creating that file path?

Answer (score 0):

Use double `\\` forward to get a proper path in your windows system.

Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
F:\\cust_files\\1360235457810_customer_xlsx.xlsx.csv
```

Comment: I actually tried this but it didnt work too... :( gave me the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this path
`F:\\cust_files\\1360235457810_customer_xlsx.xlsx.csv`

The path are separated by `\` but we need to escape this so for that you need to add one more slash `\`. Hence it becomes `\\`
Hope this helps

Comment: I tried out that, but still gets the same exception and the path gets fixed as  F:cust_files1360235457810_customer_xlsx.xlsx.csv

Comment: Try this way `F:\/cust_files\/1360235457810_customer_xlsx.xlsx.csv`

Answer (score 0):

you must replace all the \ in the path by \\

use

```
String after = before.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```